# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Fetch on Window. Express Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

**Error Message : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name**

*Looked around I have no idea what's wrong*. I'm trying to create a website to eventually send a GET request to a third-party server. But this code was a test to see how I can send data from client-side to my server.

```
let summoner = "playerName.value";    
let fetchData = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type:": "application/son user search choice"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(summoner)
    };

    fetch("/", fetchData);
```

Server Code

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.listen(4000, () => console.log("listening at 4000"));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  // res.send("POST request to the homepage")
  console.log(req);
});
```

Comment: I think your Content-Type is incorrect, which is causing the error.. It should be "application/json"

Comment: No Content-Type is just a header for giving context.

Comment: You're right, however your "Content-Type" is showing as "Content-Type:" with a colon. Remove the colon and it should work. Just tested this out myself and adding the colon there gave me the same error that you received, as "Content-Type:" is an invalid header (invalid name), but removing the colon was successful.

Comment: @Chris is correct. The standard for interpreting http headers is as colon separated key value pairs. Putting an extra colon in an HTTP header breaks the spec. Fetch checks for this and throws a TypeError instead of letting the user send a broken request.

Comment: OMG I LOVE YOU! Your exactly right, sorry I should have paid attention to what you said more.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused because you are using middlewares after call the `app.listen()`

Maybe this will resolve your problem:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(express.static("public"));
/* I added cors middleware because if your client is isolated, will be able to call your server.*/
app.use(cors());

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    // res.send("POST request to the homepage")
    console.log(req);
});
app.listen(4000, () => console.log("listening at 4000"));
```

If you are using just vanilla JS i recommend you to use [***XmlHttpRequest***](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHTTPRequest) to call your server, but if you are using an JS framework i recommend to use [***axios***](https://github.com/axios/axios)